# how to get id for use in another function in controller laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I'm trying to use the id from my show function in my controller,

My controller works correctly with this $id

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $DigestReport = Meo::find($id);
    return view('digest-report.show', ['DigestReport' => $DigestReport]);
}
```

I'm trying to use the same $id for another function

```
    public function getMailRecipients($id){
    $meoId = Meo::find(id);
    $mailRecipients = $this->meoRepository->getMailRecipients($meoId);
    return DataTables::of($mailRecipients)->make();

}
```

but I get the following error

> Too few arguments to function
> DigestReportController::getMailRecipients(), 0 passed on line 54 and
> exactly 1 expected

How can I fix it?

added: if necessary, this is my repository

```
public function getMailRecipients($meoId){
    return DB::table('mail_recipients')->where('meo_id', '=', $meoId)->select('id', 'name', 'email')->get();
```

My api.php where are my stored routes

```
Route::get('/digest-report/mail-recipients', 'DigestReportController@getMailRecipients')->name('digest-report.mail-recipients');
```

My view where I'm using this controller, is for make a datatable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mail-recipient-table').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": '{{route('digest-report.mail-recipients')}}',
                "columns": [{data:'id'},{data: 'name'},{data: 'email'}]
            });
        })
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your routes and where you call `getMailRecipients($id)`.

Comment: @mmabdelgawad updated, thanks

Comment: There is no `{id}` in your route, so it can never enter your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you have two ways to do this

1. in your `web.php` you will update your route to be

```
Route::get('/digest-report/mail-recipients/{id}', 'DigestReportController@getMailRecipients')->name('digest-report.mail-recipients');
```

then you javascript code will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mail-recipient-table').DataTable({
         "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,
          "ajax": '{{route('digest-report.mail-recipients', $DigestReport->id)}}',
          "columns": [{data:'id'},{data: 'name'},{data: 'email'}]
    });
})
```

2. in you controller you will update `getMailRecipients`

```
public function getMailRecipients(Request $request){
    $meoId = Meo::find($request->id); // or using helper request('id') function
    $mailRecipients = $this->meoRepository->getMailRecipients($meoId);
    return DataTables::of($mailRecipients)->make();
}
```

and your javascript code will be the same

Comment: thanks for reply, now I have the following error

$id is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $id }} with {{ $id ?? '' }}

Comment: ok, I added $DigestReport->id in the js and the problem is solved, thanks!